# Right way to use a variant for user defined template class

Tags: c++, c++17

I am pretty new to std::variant and C++17 feature. I know that variant can store multiple types, but maybe it would not allow the user defined template class.

I was wondering if I could use the following.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    A(T value) : _value(value){}
public:
    T _value;

};

using variant_t = std::variant<A<std::string>, A<int>, A<bool>, A<double>, A<unsigned int>, A<unsigned short>>;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, variant_t> Foo;
    Foo = {{"name", A("name")}};
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure how I am getting a syntax error, and it's saying that compiler cannot deduce template argument for std::unordered_map. But if i use the `using variant_t = std::variant<A<std::string>, A<int>, A<bool>, A<double>, A<unsigned int>, A<unsigned short>>;` inside of main. the syntax errors have gone. Than, there is errors in xhash saying that `unary '++': '_Iter' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator` and `binary !=: _iter does not define this operator of a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`.

Does this mean that I would have to initialize one of the types while using the variant?

Comment: Seung Ho Jang, did the answer solve your problem or do you need me to clarify anything?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it makes sense! I really appreciated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
Foo = {{"name", A("name")}};
```

This would deduce the `A` instance to `A<const char*>`, not `A<std::string>`.

If you want to use the assignment operator taking an initializer list, you'll have to help it to get the contained types right:

```cpp
Foo = {std::pair<const std::string, variant_t>{"name", variant_t("name")}};
```

or simply

```cpp
Foo = {{"name", variant_t("name")}};
```

or even

```cpp
Foo = {{"name", A<std::string>("name")}};
```

---

Another option is to add a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for `A`:

```cpp
A(const char*) -> A<std::string>;
```

That deduction guide will then let you use your original form:

```cpp
Foo = {{"name", A("name")}};
```